# htaccess redirect image request if current url contain specific string

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect image request if current url contain specific string, for example `/id/`

so far i tried the following syntax on htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /id
RewriteRule (.*)/image1.png$ $1/image1-id.png
```

i am not good with htaccess, please point me.

Comment: Question isn't clear. What URL do you want to show in browser and how it should be handled internally?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/id/(.*)$
rewriterule ^image1.png(.*)$ image1-id.png$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i forgot that the URL `/something/id/` comefrom a redirection from `/something/` if some condition in php code is true. therefore i use `RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_URL} /something/id/`, how di i merge my modification with yours?

Comment: please see my comment :)